# Symfony2 form validation groups based on submitted data

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have some complex form, with several subforms, and I want to be able to validate each subform separately depending on radio button choosen in main form. I wanted to achieve this with validation groups.

Note: I have no `data_class` model, I work with arrays.

Here is my form simplified:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('xxx', 'text', array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                ),
                'validation_groups' => array(
                    'xxx',
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
                return array('xxx');
            },
        ));
    }
}
```

The problem is that validation for this field is not triggered.

When this works, I can easily change `setDefaultOptions` to validate desired group depending on submitted data:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            return array($data['type']);
        },
    ));
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to pass the validation group name to the constraint, not in the form itself. By assigning group name to a form you specify which constraints to use in validation.

Replace

```
$builder->add('xxx', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new Constraints\NotBlank(),
        ),
        'validation_groups' => array(
            'xxx',
        )
    ))
;
```

With

```
$builder->add('xxx', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new Constraints\NotBlank(array(
                'groups' => 'xxx'
            )),
        ),
    ))
;
```

By default, constraints have the '*Default*' (capitalized) group and forms use this group to validate if none specified. If you want the other constraints with no explicit group to validate, along with specified group pass the '*Default*' one.

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        return array($data['type'], 'Default');
    },
));
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But what is `validation_groups` in form used for then?
Regarding default group, constant Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint::DEFAULT_GROUP can be used.

Comment: It used for specifying groups for validation. For instance, you can pass general validation groups to the main form and override the groups in sub form. Field forms (e.g. text, choice) are the same as main form (e.g. MyType form in the subject).

Comment: This answer does not answer the question *I want to be able to validate each subform separately*. Becuase passing the validation_groups only works on the main form. Setting a validation_groups directly to a child form does not work.