# Validation error when submit form in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I create a form for register users:

```php
$builder
->add('username', TelType::class)
->add('passwordField', PasswordType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank([
            'message' => 'Error'
        ]),
        new Length([
            'min' => 6,
            'minMessage' => 'Error'
        ])
    ]
])
->add('firstname')
->add('lastname')
->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'constraints' => [
        new IsTrue([
            'message' => 'PLEASE CHECK AGREE TERMS'
        ])
    ]
])
->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
```

Now I want add users with admin panel. I create a "add user" page in my admin panel.

I don't want to add "agreeTerms" checkbox in my "add user" page in admin panel.

but when I submit my form, validation error and show "PLEASE CHECK AGREE TERMS".

AgreeTerms in daabas can not null.

I use this in my twig template for don't show agreeTerms checkbox:

```
{{ form_start(addUsersForm) }}
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(addUsersForm.username, {
                'required': true
            })}}
            {{ form_label(addUsersForm.username) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(addUsersForm.pass, {
                'required': true
            })}}
            {{ form_label(addUsersForm.pass) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(addUsersForm.name)}}
            {{ form_label(addUsersForm.name) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(addUsersForm.lastname)}}
            {{ form_label(addUsersForm.lastname) }}
        </div>
{{ form_end(addUsersForm, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: So you have a form on your front-end side with checkbox, which has to be selected, but this field has to be skipped on your admin page?

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Hi, yes users must select checkbox but in admin panel we don't need to show and select checkbox and in in admin regiser page controller I set agreeterms for database because it's not null in database

Comment: You might organize each constraint into 1 or more “validation groups” and then apply validation against 1 group of constraints. For ex., fields which are going to be checked on your front-end and on the admin page you might mark with `'groups' => ['Default', 'registration']` or `'groups' => ['admin', 'registration']`. And fields which have to be checked on front-end only as `'groups' => ['registration']`. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13200272/2224394 and https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add this to your form create, like:

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class,null,[
    'validation_groups' => ['adminRegistration']
]);
```

And end of UserType.php add this:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
        'validation_groups' => ['registration']
    ]);
}
```

Then change agreeterms to this:

```
->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'constraints' => [
        new IsTrue([
            'groups' => 'registration',
            'message' => 'PLEASE CHECK AGREE TERMS'
        ])
    ]
])
```